# TypeError: moment.localeData is not a function Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, momentjs

Im facing this error when i try to run my project. I have searched for similar problems and found [this](https://github.com/jalaali/moment-jalaali/issues/182)

but the problem with that is i haven't ejected my app so I cant configure webpack and also i didn't feel the need to eject it
in CRA.md i just imported locales as follow

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr';
import 'moment/locale/fa';
moment.locale("fa");
```

i'm using *"moment-jalaali": "^0.7.4"*

I don't know what more information i have to provide. I would be so happy if i can get any help

[image: here is the error]

Comment: can you please replace `moment-jalaali` with the standard `moment` library...

Comment: tried that and had the same error

Comment: [moment.localeData()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) is available only from version 2.8.0+

Comment: moment-jalaali requires ^ 2.22.2

Comment: file:
/node_modules/moment-jalaali/index.js

replace: (line 4)

var moment = require('moment')
to
var moment = require('moment/moment')